# Internet Explorer opens a new pop -up window on window.close() and then closes the newly opened popup

Tags: c#, javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a pop up window which basically takes text fields inputs for entry in a grid view (asp) which is in my parent form/page, I post back to the parent back so that the newly added data from the pop-up is reflected in the parent page.

Although this flow goes smoothly in Chrome or firefox, It gives a weird problem  when I use the same logic in IE,

To explain the problem let me give you the background of my code
     ,This is how I open the pop-up window from the parent page:

```
 <asp:Button ID="AddBtn" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClientClick="javascript:OpenChildWindow();" Text="Add"/> 



   function OpenChildWindow()
    {
        //open a new dialog window
        var sFeatures="dialogHeight: 500px;";
        sFeatures += "dialogWidth: 800px;";
        sFeatures += "center: yes;";
        sFeatures += "edge: sunken;";
        sFeatures += "scroll: no;";
        sFeatures += "status: yes;";
        sFeatures += "resizeable: no;";
        var url = 'TransNewEntry.aspx?SomeValue=12345';

        entryWindow=window.showModalDialog(url, 'TransNewEntry', sFeatures);            

    }
```

This is how I try to close it after the user  clicks save button in the pop-up window:

```
  protected void saveRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       {/*some code to insert/modify datarow*/
        }
        Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'> window.open('','_self',''); window.close();</script>");
    }
```

So what happens now is when I click save button (in the pop-up window)  instead of closing the current window ,it opens a new window(duplicate of the pop-up window already opened) and closes that newly opened window.

Note that I have used "window.open('','_self','');" before "window.close" if I only use "window.close"  IE throws a confirmation box on whether I should close the newly open pop-up but it opens the a duplicate pop up regardlessly .

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but are you sure you need pop-ups? These, and modal dialogs, are pretty dated, and pop-up blockers will block them. Why not lightbox it?

Comment: Well pop-up is a requirement and also I don't have a clue about light box

Comment: They've required that you specifically use popups and not a lightbox variant? When I say lightbox, I mean simulated popups - effectively DHTML. Like what happens if you click one of the 'close' or 'flag' links underneath a question here on SO.

Comment: hmm this is something new I have to research a bit,if you have some good links to for me start up from please share

Comment: There's plenty of lightbox scripts out there. Check out http://fancybox.net/